# Vanishing images in Notes browser app

Tags: notes.app

What I like about Apple's note app is that it supports pictures. However, when I use the browser interface, the pictures disappear after I inserted them and switch to another note. Also, they are not downloaded to the Notes desktop app.

Is there something I could do about it?

Comment: I assume you use copy paste from Internet to notes.

Comment: I think he means copy pictures in the web interface (iCould) of notes. When you have a picture on the clipboard, you can do CMD+V and it will show up on your note on iCloud, but it will not save/sync to your iPhone/your desktop app.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was doing. I thought this might be a particular problem, but it seems that this feature is not supported in general

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the web interface (iCloud) supports adding pictures (yet). The only way to add pictures to a note is using notes.app from the Applications folder, but you figured that out already.

Comment: I thought that this might be a glitch or bug, but okay, now I know that this feature is not supported